# How to use libfuzzers custom mutators API?

Tags: clang, fuzzing, libfuzzer

Libfuzzer offers two APIs to develop custom mutators.

```
size_t LLVMFuzzerCustomMutator(uint8_t *Data, size_t Size, size_t MaxSize, unsigned int Seed)
size_t LLVMFuzzerCustomCrossOver(const uint8_t *Data1, size_t Size1, const uint8_t *Data2, size_t Size2, uint8_t *Out, size_t MaxOutSize, unsigned int Seed)
```

How are these APIs supposed to be used?
The fuzzer is required to be deterministic. How do I ensure that with the custom mutators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to implement those functions alongside your `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput`.

The [google/fuzzing repository has a tutorial on how to implement structure-aware fuzzing](https://github.com/google/fuzzing/blob/bb05211c12328cb16327bb0d58c0c67a9a44576f/docs/structure-aware-fuzzing.md).

Also, you could take inspiration from [CustomMutatorTest.cpp](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/f623dc9a8c37c3f2ed0a2138563a8b9e37adc1ce/compiler-rt/test/fuzzer/CustomMutatorTest.cpp), and [CustomCrossOverTest.cpp](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/f623dc9a8c37c3f2ed0a2138563a8b9e37adc1ce/compiler-rt/test/fuzzer/CustomCrossOverTest.cpp), from the LLVM repository.

> The fuzzer is required to be deterministic.

Right, but here you will be writing the mutation functions, which are different; Mutations will happen before your `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput` is called.

However, they have an analogous requirement.
As outlined in the [source code](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/compiler-rt/lib/fuzzer/FuzzerInterface.h#L49-L64), alongside `LLVMFuzzerCustomMutator`, and `LLVMFuzzerCustomCrossOver` respectively:

> Optional user-provided custom mutator.
> Mutates raw data in [Data, Data+Size) inplace.
> Returns the new size, which is not greater than MaxSize.
> Given the same Seed produces the same mutation.

> Optional user-provided custom cross-over function.
> Combines pieces of Data1 & Data2 together into Out.
> Returns the new size, which is not greater than MaxOutSize.
> Should produce the same mutation given the same Seed.

**i.e.** Two calls to a mutation function with the same `Data` and `seed` should produce the same result.

One last thing: you don't need to implement both functions;  `LLVMFuzzerCustomMutator` should be enough in most cases.